# How to Set a multiline string replacement in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I was developing a bat file to run my experiment with two varying parameters for each alpha1 there is 10 ws value, i use the bat file to change the variable inside the experiment code and to make 20 files of alpha with 10 subfolder in each alpha folder , i can't see where is the problem

```
@Echo off
SET "file=synch-ring.f"
SET /a Line#ToSearch1=14
SET /a Line#ToSearch2=27
FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,20) do (
FOR /L %%J IN (1,1,10) do (
md %%I
md %%I\%%J
(FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') DO (
    SET "Line=%%a"
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch% SET "Line=        Alpha1=%%I"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line! 
    ENDLOCAL
    IF %%a equ %Line#ToSearch2% SET "Line=        ws=%%J"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    ECHO(!Line!
    ENDLOCAL
    ))"%%J.f"
Move %%J.f %%I\%%J
))
pause
```

Comment: There are multiple issues. First, we can't look what your batch file does without knowing content of file `synch-ring.f`. Second, there is no `>` in your code to redirect output to handle __STDOUT__ to a file. Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). Third, why using `"%%J.f"` and next move the file not created because of missing `>`? Better would be `>"%%I\%%J\%%J.f"` and remove the move command to directly create the file in appropriate directory.

Comment: Fourth, don't use `set /A` if you just assign a string or number to an environment variable. There is usually absolutely no need to use an __arithmetic expression__ to assign a string like `14` or `27` to an environment variable which are always of type string. An environment variable of type integer is not possible. Fifth, depending on content of file `synch-ring.f` it is most likely better to use a string comparison than an integer comparison by using `IF "%%~a" == "%Line#ToSearch%"` to prevent an exit of batch file execution because of a syntax error depending on value of loop variable `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure that I've properly understood your intent, but this may be helpful to you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "file=synch-ring.f"
Set "Line#ToSearch1=14"
Set "Line#ToSearch2=27"
If Not Exist "%file%" Exit /B
For /L %%I In (1,1,20) Do (
    For /L %%J In (1,1,10) Do (
        MD "%%I\%%J" 2>Nul
        (
            For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" "%file%"'
            ) Do (
                If %%A NEq %Line#ToSearch% (
                    If %%A NEq %Line#ToSearch2% (
                        Echo=%%B
                    ) Else (
                        Echo=        ws=%%J
                    )
                ) Else (
                    Echo=        Alpha1=%%I"
                )
            )
        )>"%%I\%%J\%%J.f"
    )
)
Pause
```